# New primitives and grammar for replacing horrible \expandafter

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, primitives

Time and time when I am trying to read or write some macros, I'm always frustrated by lots of `\expandafter`s inside them. Why don't we add some new primitives and grammar into TeX engines to make macros writing and reading more easier?

My idea is to use `(` and `)` as new group opening and closing characters **in some contexts**. `(` and `)` acts like `{` and `}`, but when TeX encounter them in some context, it firstly expands tokens inside them completely just like `\edef`. For example

```
\expandfirston
\def\cmd(replacement)  % same as \edef\cmd{replacement}
\expandfistoff
```

Another example：

```
\expandfirston
\def\cmd#1#2{replacement}
\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % firstly expands \cmd, then \arga and \argb
\cmd(\arga){\argb}  % firstly expands \arga, then \cmd, lastly \argb
\cmd{\arga}(\argb)  % firstly expands \argb, then \cmd, lastly \arga
\cmd(\arga)(\argb)  % firstly expands \arga, then \argb, lastly \cmd
\expandfirstoff
```

The third example：

```
\expandfirston
\def\cmda#1{replacementa}
\def\cmdb#1{replacementb}
\cmdb(\cmda(\arg))% firstly expands \arg, then \cmda, lastly \cmdb
\expandfirstoff
```

For compatibility, We may restrict the new grammar only takes effect in defining macros and calling macros, and some assignments, etc.

My questions are the followings:

1. Are there any shortcoming with this new grammar?
2. If I want to implement this new grammar as macros, which existing macros could I refer to?
3. If someone implements this new grammar in TeX engine, would `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex` accept this patch and new primitives?

Comment: This is edef expansion `x` expansion in latex3 terminoligy, which would not really help in most uses of `\expandafter` much of the latex3 `xparse` syntax is designed to hide \expandafter so `\expandafter\foo\csname x \endcsname ` becomes `\foo:c{x}` for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Some times ago I tried to learn latex3, but its grammer also frustrated me. ...

Comment: Perhaps, but you asked for existing macros. Do you really mean same as \edef or same as \expandafter? the title says \expandafter but you say \edef in the code (edef expansion is a tricky thing and the source of all the issues with \protect

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I misunderstood your last comment. Thanks.

Comment: The problem here I think is that TeX works a _very_ different way from the functional-like approach you propose. Moreover, this isn't a new primitive syntax but a new pair(?) of catcodes for the behaviour desired. That's very tricky to imagine as a patch without major work. I'd note that engine changes tend to address things TeX _cannot_ do, not simply ones that are 'oddities': `\expandafter` does work perfectly well for the semantics DEK defined.

Comment: Also, note that `\expandafter` is a single defined expansion, which is different to `\edef` behaviour, so the above proposal doesn't negate the need for `\expandafter`. For example, the 'classic' `\expandafter\foo\temp\stop` to do a delimited grab on something stored in `\temp` doesn't necessarily require exhaustive expansion of `\temp`.

Comment: I guess you've looked at things like `etoolbox` for a macro-based approach to controlling expansion which uses a more 'traditional' syntax to `expl3`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to separate out the choice of the `:` and `_` syntax of L3 from the functionality.

The following uses a much smaller expansion library than xparse (just 7 lines of code) but it implements the `n` (no expansion) `x` (full `\edef` expansion) and `o` (expand once `\expandafter`) expansion types.

Rather than define variant macro names with `:nnx` suffixes, just explicitly prefix the use with a `\use` command that specifies how to expand the arguments (which is also the basis of xparse syntax).

Note how with `o`, `\argb` just expands once to `bbb {\arga}` before `\cmd` is called but with `x`, `\argb` fully expands to `bbb {aa}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\use#1{\xuse#1z}
\def\xuse#1{\csname use#1\endcsname}
\def\usez#1{#1}
\long\def\usen#1z#2#3{\xuse#1z{#2{#3}}}
\long\def\useo#1z#2#3{\expandafter\useohelp\expandafter{#3}{#1}{#2}}
\long\def\useohelp#1#2#3{\xuse#2z{#3{#1}}}
\protected\long\def\usex#1z#2#3{\edef\usetmp{#3}\expandafter\useohelp\expandafter{\usetmp}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}



\def\cmd#1#2{{\ttfamily\par\def\a{#1}\#1:\meaning\a \quad\#2:\def\a{#2}\meaning\a\par}}
\def\arga{aa}
\def\argb{bbb {\arga}}



        \cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % normal
\use{nn}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % normal
\use{on}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #1 once 
\use{no}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #2 once
\use{oo}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #1 and #2 once
\use{xx}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % fully (\edef) expand #1 and #2

\end{document}
```

As noted in comments it isn't at all clear whether you intended your `()` syntax to correspond to `o` or `x` but either way It is really better handled at the macro layer rather than a change of the engine expansion logic.

Comment: Perhaps add a group (and `\protected` status) for `\usex`?

Comment: @JosephWright `\protected`: you're so modern:-)

Comment: @JosephWright I added `\protected` adding a group would require a bit of reaarangement and I think here I'm happy for the definition of `\usetmp` to leak.

Comment: Which is the same as `expl3` does, because `\zh_cmd:oo` is defined as `\exp_args:Noo\zh_cmd:nn`.

Comment: @egreg yes, It's a copy of expl3 (from memory:-)

Comment: +1 This simply demonstrates that no special features at primitive level is needed. The arbitrary number of parameters can be used. You can correct your code: `\def\usez#1{#1}` because without this all processing is done in unwanted group.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with `expl3`:

```
\input expl3-generic

\def\arga{what}
\def\argb{how}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npx \zh_cmda: { \arga\argb }

\cs_new:Npn \zh_cmdb:nn #1 #2
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { what }
   { \msg_term:n{\#1~is~`what'} }
   { \msg_term:n{\#1~isn't~`what'} }
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { how }
   { \msg_term:n{\#2~is~`how'} }
   { \msg_term:n{\#2~isn't~`how'} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \zh_cmdb:nn { no }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \zh_cmdb:nn { on }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \zh_cmdb:nn { oo }

\msg_term:n
 {
  The ~ replacement ~ text ~ of ~ \exp_not:N \zh_cmda: ~ is ~
  `\token_get_replacement_spec:N \zh_cmda:'
 }
\zh_cmdb:nn { \arga } { \argb }
\zh_cmdb:no { \arga } { \argb }
\zh_cmdb:on { \arga } { \argb }
\zh_cmdb:oo { \arga } { \argb }

\bye
```

The terminal session will show

```
*************************************************
* The replacement text of \zh_cmda: is `whathow'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #1 isn't `what'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #2 isn't `how'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #1 isn't `what'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #2 is `how'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #1 is `what'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #2 isn't `how'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #1 is `what'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* #2 is `how'
*************************************************
```

Note that the result is what's expected: the argument are expanded once when `o` is used, making the `\str_if_eq:nnTF` test succeed.

Do you need to use `expl3` syntax in your code? Not at all! Just define a suitable wrapper. With `\exp_args_generate:n` you can define all the variants you need.

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \use #1 { \cs_if_exist_use:cF { exp_args:N#1 } { \ERROR } }
\exp_args_generate:n { nn, on, ee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\cmd#1#2{{\tt\par\def\a{#1}\#1:\meaning\a \quad\#2:\def\a{#2}\meaning\a\par}}
\def\arga{aa}
\def\argb{bbb {\arga}}



        \cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % normal
\use{nn}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % normal
\use{on}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #1 once 
\use{no}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #2 once
\use{oo}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % expand #1 and #2 once
\use{xx}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % fully (\edef) expand #1 and #2
\use{ee}\cmd{\arga}{\argb}  % fully (\edef) expand #1 and #2

\bye
```

The last is the new `e`-type expansion, which is similar to `x`-expansion, but is fully expandable itself. If a variant is not defined, you get an error message. Of course `\use{nn}` is the same as nothing.

[image]

The advantage is that you can define variants for as many arguments as you need. So if `\macro` has three arguments, you can use

```
\use{noe}\macro{<first>}{<second>}{<third>}
```

and accomplish the desired expansions before `\macro` is actually called, provided you add `noe` to the list of known variants.

Comment: The problem is that, in my opinion, `expl3` code is also horrible to read or write.

Comment: @Z.H. Blasphemy! ;-)

Comment: @Z.H. Well, the syntax you propose can't be realized with macros without sacrificing full expandability.

Comment: @Z.H. Once upon a time I found English horrible to read and write. But then I learned it and now it's easy. With expl3 it was just the same. Actually it was better because I learned a lot about TeX and expansion by learning expl3 :)

Comment: @cgnieder If there are two choices, most people would choose the simple one rather than the horrible one.

Comment: @Z.H. You still misunderstood me: expl3 *is* the simpler choice!